# IIS6 using intranet user's credentials to authorize writing to file server

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-6

Good afternoon,

I was wondering if it is possible to enable a web application to use the (intranet) authenticated user's permissions to write to a network path?

I was playing with application pool identities but I cannot seem to find the correct way to do things.

To clarify:

All machines are on the company intranet.
User has write permissions to file server, web application authenticates user

**Local Machine <> Web Server <> File Server**

How do I wire up my ASP.net application correctly to use the windows user's account and not the application username? My web.config uses windows authentication: `<authentication mode="Windows"/>`

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: on the appliction config file change the authentication mode to Windows  it will start using the windows account instead of the application account.

Comment: are you referring to web.config? I am using windows authentication there.

Comment: Yes he means web.config

Comment: Thank you. I have my web.config set to <authentication mode="Windows"/>, however, it still gives me an access denied error. If I run the application locally it saves the file without a problem.

Comment: when you set the auth mode to windows it is using the current windows account of the system in which your browsing the application, that account should have access to the resources in the server in order to read and write. you will need to create a role in your domain controller and add all the user which you want to access   the server to that role and let that role have access to this server. let me know if I am not clear.

Comment: I am sure these the are  basics of OS and you can do it. let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks again, the user is in the correct role and the role/user does have access to read/write to the network resource. The asp net application, however, does not correctly forward those credentials when it attempts the disk operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In our company we have the special account in Active Directory with admin'ish rights and all authenticated users impersonates with it.

In web.config it goes like that:

```xml
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Windows"/>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
  </authorization>
  <identity impersonate="true" password="passforadminaccount" userName="loginforadminaccount"/>
</system.web>
```

Sorry, if I got you wrong and provided useless information.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. This is what we ended up doing. Thank you!